# aliasing problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vector-graphics

the code below draws two vertical lines on a canvas. these lines appear to be of different thickness on the screen although they are the same in code. i am tying to find a way to make them look as sharp as the border around the canvas. setting Path.SnapsToDevicePixels does not have any effect. The code is a contrived example, and in general the canvas that plots these lines can be nested deeper inside the visual tree.

thanks for any help
konstantin

```
<Window x:Class="wpfapp.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Margin="10">
      <Canvas x:Name="Canvas"
              SizeChanged="OnCanvasSizeChanged" />
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace wpfapp
{
    public partial class MyWindow : Window
    {
        public MyWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCanvasSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamGeometry g = new StreamGeometry();
            double h = this.Canvas.ActualHeight;

            using (StreamGeometryContext c = g.Open())
            {
                c.BeginFigure(new Point(7, 0), false, false);
                c.LineTo(new Point(7, h), true, false);

                c.BeginFigure(new Point(14, 0), false, false);
                c.LineTo(new Point(14, h), true, false);
            }
            g.Freeze();

            Path p = new Path();

            p.Data = g;
            p.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
            p.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            p.StrokeThickness = 1;

            this.Canvas.Children.Clear();
            this.Canvas.Children.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but try setting SnapsToDevicePixels on every element in the tree containing the Canvas.  Snapping an individual element to device pixels doesn't help if the vectors are transformed to unaligned coordinates further up the rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to use GuidelineSet:

```
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext c)
        {
            base.OnRender(c);

            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
            double h = this.ActualHeight;
            double d = pen.Thickness / 2;

            foreach (double x in new double[] { 7, 14 })
            {
                GuidelineSet g = new GuidelineSet(new double[] { x + d },
                                                  new double[] { 0 + d, h + d });

                c.PushGuidelineSet(g);
                c.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, 0), new Point(x, h));
                c.Pop();
            }
        }
```